# How can I make a webpage visible once a day?

Tags: php

I am making an html/php quiz, but I don't want people to be able to do it more than once a day. So how can I check whether they have uploaded in the last 24 hours?

Comment: the only reliable way is to use a login system

Comment: Behind login or ask for email.

Comment: Or create a table where store `ip address`,`user_final_satus`,`date`. of the user  . on that quiz page do the query that `ip addres` comes today on my page or not? if yes restrict it

Comment: addition to @Anant comment, make date and ip as unique. Coz next day same ip can be assigned to your other/new user.

Comment: @Jigar he said `I don't want people to be able to do it more than once a day` means every day same ip can attend one time his page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a user system?

If so when user people finished save the username and the date in your datebase.
When people try to access your page check if they didn't already complete the game.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this question as answered, it'll be easier for future user who ask the same as you did to find the answer.